# Is there a widely used library of patterns & interfaces for .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, .net-3.5, code-reuse

I'd like to avoid coding my own version of IFactory, ILog, IRepository and other common interfaces & implementations in my projects but find that commonly used libraries containing these tend to be focused on a particular concrete subsystem (one ORM, one IoC container, one logger). I've come across a some that seem more abstract (NCommon has three repository implementations) but I was wondering if there are any you could add or recommend?

- [Rhino.Commons](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/)
- [Tarantino](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/)
- [NCommon](http://code.google.com/p/ncommon/)

Thanks!

James

PS - My original question was a bit too general, but I greatly appreciate your answers and recommendations and will check them all out.

Comment: Seems like this would best be a community wiki.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, I stupidly wasn't as specific as I planned on being in my question though (will edit it)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/)

- [ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) - [Active Record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) implementation leveraging NHibernate
- [ActiveWriter](http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/ActiveWriter) - Visual Design Environment for NHibernate or ActiveRecord
- [Windsor IoC Container](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html)
- [MonoRail MVC Framework](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/index.html)
- [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)

[Sprint.NET](http://springframework.net/)

- "Spring.NET is an open source application framework that makes building  enterprise .NET applications easier" (from website)

Others...

- [Structure Map](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) - IoC Container
- [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) - Object to Object mapping

Comment: All the answers were good, had to pick one, thanks to every for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Design Pattern Framework](http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx) at the data & object factory.  They have implementations of tons of patterns.  And of course there is [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One of the best .NET open source library projects, in my opinion, is the Castle Project. They have an MVC called MonoRail (however ASP.NET MVC is now much better), an ActiveRecord implementation, and an IoC Container called MicroKernel/Windsor. There are also many other smaller but useful libraries like DynamicProxy.

Currently my favorite .NET library project.

http://www.castleproject.org/

For a GREAT enterprise service bus, I much prefer to use Udi Dahan's NServiceBus, which is free, open source, and extremely efficient (one case study showed a throughput of 100 million durable and 900 million non-durable messages per hour...a billion message throughput.)

http://www.nservicebus.com/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the [Microsoft Patterns and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) site has some good information...

[Prism Composite Application Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490815.aspx) is particularly relevant to your question.

+1 to Castle Project too!